# How to configure Hudson

Tags: hudson, jenkins

Actually I was trying to configure Hudson for Junit test.In the configure page I have checked `Publish JUnit test result report`. And I have to add `Test report XMLs`. Since I am new to Hudson I dont know what I have to add there. I am getting an error like,`'**/build/test-reports/*.xml' doesn't match anything, but '*.xml' does. Perhaps that's what you mean?`.

Please help me by providing some tutorials.
I am using GAE with JSF2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a warning. It means that the files do not as yet exist. Save and run the job. If then the files are not there you'll get a failure that you need to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - also, you need to update your ant target xml :

ensure your logdir is correct :